# Integer matrices multiplication problem (while proving integrality of the $j$-invariant)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, modular-forms

I came across this problem while studying modular forms (while proving the integrality of the $j$-invariant) but I guess that the solution can found in some linear algebra reasoning.

Given $$T=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$$ such that $ad=n$, $0\leq b <d$.

I would like to show that 
$$ T= A \begin{pmatrix} d_1& 0 \\ 0 & d_2 \end{pmatrix} B $$
for some $A,B \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$  and $d_1d_2=n$, $d_2\mid d_1$

I had some ideas considering the matrices of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as base changes of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $T,\begin{pmatrix}d_1&0\\0& d_2 \end{pmatrix}$ as endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, but I couldn't figure out the way to do it.

Any hint or reference that treats integer matrices problems like this one would be appreciated as much as a solution.

Comment: It is actually required to prove that $A_n = \bigcup\limits_{d_1d_2=n, d_2\mid d_1} \Gamma \begin{pmatrix} d_1 &0 \\0& d_2 \end {pmatrix} \Gamma $ for $\Gamma=SL_2 (\mathbb {Z}) $. But I already proved that $A_n= \bigcup \Gamma \begin {pmatrix} a & b \\ 0&d \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Wait. Yes $A_n =\displaystyle \bigcup_{ad = n, b \bmod d} A_1{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix}}$, since ${\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}}{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix}}= {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & b +d\\ 0& d \end{pmatrix}}$ and ${\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix}}{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}}= {\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & b +a\\ 0& d \end{pmatrix}}$, you can obtain $b= 0$  iff $\gcd(a,d) =1$, which happens in general when $n$ is square-free

Comment: With that established, it is enough to prove what I asked above. And the statement ia for a general  $n$, not necessarily square free